# How do i generate and sum up random numbers from an array in javascript and python

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that takes an array and a target number. The goal is two generate any two random numbers from the array and sum them up. If the sum of the two random integers is equal to the target number, I then have to return the index of the two random numbers in the array.

Here is my code so far, I keep getting a stderr. How do you recommend I go about this.

```
function twoSum (numbers, target) {
  let numIdx = [];
  let sum = 0;
  let firstValue = 0;
  let secValue = 0

  while(sum !== target) {
    firstValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    secValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    sum = firstValue + secValue;
    
    if (sum === target) {
      numIdx.push(numbers[firstValue])
      numIdx.push(numbers[secValue])
      return numIdx
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add in the code that shows how you're calling this function, so we know what values are being passed into the parameters.  Also, at what point are you getting the error, and what is the text of the error?

Comment: Are you trying to test if *any* of the two numbers in the array could be added together to equal the target number? For example, testing if `array[0] + array[1] = target`, then testing if `array[0] + array[2] = target` and so on?

Comment: What part involves python, as your title states?

Comment: sunscreen54 if you think one of the answeres were helpful, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

currently you are summing the `indexes` and returning `values`. I think this may be issue.

try

```
sum = numbers[firstValue] + numbers[secValue];

and 

return [firstValue, secValue]
```

```js
function twoSum (numbers, target, max_trials = 100) {
  let sum = 0;
  let first = 0;
  let sec = 0
  let trials = 0;
  
  const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);

  while(sum !== target && trials++ < max_trials ) {
    first = rand();
    sec = rand();
    sum = numbers[first] + numbers[sec];
    
    if (sum === target) {
      console.log('Trials: ', trials)
      return [first, sec];
    }
  }
  console.log('Trials maxed out: ', trials)
}

const data = [1, 4, 7, 3, 11, 9];
const target = 15; // expecting 1, 4

console.log(twoSum(data, target))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

- Generate two indices with random number in the boundaries of the length of your array.
- Sum up the values at the indices when the sum is equal to target then return the indices.

```js
function twoSum(numbers, target) {
  let numIdx = [];
  let sum = 0;
 

  while (sum !== target) {
    let firstIndic = getRandomInt(numbers.length);
    let firstValue = numbers[firstIndic];
    let secIndic = getRandomInt(numbers.length);
    let secValue = numbers[secIndic];
    sum = firstValue + secValue;

    if (sum === target) {
      numIdx.push(firstIndic)
      numIdx.push(secIndic)
      return numIdx
    }
  }
}


function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

console.log(twoSum([
  12,
  5,
  4,
  9
], 21));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array of numbers

Then for each one of those numbers loop through again and check if `number1` + `number2` is equal to your `target` and also that `number1` and `number2` arent at the same position in the array (unless that's okay with you)

and return each index

```js
function twoSum(numbers, target) {
  // Loop through the array of numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    const number1 = numbers[i];

    for (let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      const number2 = numbers[j];
      // Check if number1 + number2 is equal to target and also make sure number1 and number2 aren't at the same index in the array
      if (number1 + number2 === target && i !== j) {
        return `index 1: ${i}, index 2: ${j}`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for instance calling this `twoSum([1,2,3], 4)` would result in `index 1: 0, index 2: 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[2,5,3,4,7];
var num=5;
function twoSum (numbers, target) {
  let numIdx = [];
  let sum = 0;
  let firstValue = 0;
  let secValue = 0

  while(sum !== target) {
    firstValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(numbers.length));
    let f1=numbers[firstValue];
    secValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(numbers.length));
    let f2=numbers[secValue];
    sum = f1 + f2;
    
    if (sum === target) {
      numIdx.push(firstValue)
      numIdx.push(secValue)
      return numIdx
    }
  }
}
document.write(twoSum(arr,num));
```